# How to use a count-aggregate function directly on a pivot table?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I am looking for the equivalent in Eloquent/ Laravel to the SQL statement

```
SELECT label_id, COUNT(*) FROM label_picture WHERE picture_id IN (7,12) GROUP BY label_id
```

and don't know how to do this. Specifically I have the following many-to-many relation defined in Laravel:

```
// Picture model
public function labels() { return $this->belongsToMany('App\Label'); }

// Label model
public function pictures() { return $this->belongsToMany('App\Picture'); }
```

If I want to figure out how often each label ist used, I can simply walk through all labels and call `$label->pictures->count()` for each label. But I don't want to do this for the whole set of pictures, but only for a selected list of pictures (e. g.: ids 7 and 12 in the SQL example in the beginning).

My pivot table looks like the following:

```
label_picture:

label_id: 1, picture_id:  1
label_id: 1, picture_id:  2
label_id: 2, picture_id:  7
label_id: 2, picture_id:  3
label_id: 1, picture_id: 12
label_id: 3, picture_id:  7
label_id: 2, picture_id:  2
label_id: 1, picture_id:  7
label_id: 3, picture_id: 12
```

and the SQL statement

```
SELECT label_id, COUNT(*) FROM label_picture WHERE picture_id IN (7,12) GROUP BY label_id
```

would result in

```
label_id    COUNT(*)
1           2
2           1
3           2
```

How do I do this in Eloquent/ Laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about any eloquent method of doing this, but you can use QueryBuilder to do this like below:

```
$picture_ids = [7,12]; //replace this with your way to get picture ids
$labels = DB::table('label_picture')
            ->selectRaw('label_id,count(*) as total')
            ->whereIn('picture_id',$picture_ids)
            ->groupBy('label_id')
            ->get();
```

Comment: Works. Thanks so much. Although I hoped there ist an eleoquent method to access the pivot table.